# How to solve problems arise from switch off a lubuntu system before the bootstrap is finished?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, power-management, boot-repair

I have a system with lubuntu 22.04 installed. The system must be switched off brutally without a software shutdown.

Sometimes the system is switched off before the bootstrap process has  finished. In this case, sometimes lubuntu shows a screen with some options (recovery, UEFI Firmware, and so on).

Below I show a picture with this screen:
[image: lubuntu boot option screen]

Waiting for about 60 seconds the boot process resumes and completes successfully, but because this system must be used by other users than me, I'm asking how to solve this problem or at least to chose a set of configurations for lubuntu which drastically reduces the number of times the bootstrap is not standard.

With the term **set of configurations** I mean reduce the number of writing to the hard disk, reduce the quantity of logs or other niceties which I can use to aim my goal.

This is my question: is there a set of configuration for lubuntu which preserves lubuntu from boot problems due to brutal shutdowns?

Comment: I'd probably look for a *immutable* desktop, as current Lubuntu isn't intended for that operation (https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-core-an-immutable-linux-desktop talks about that coming to Ubuntu Desktop.. but other non-Ubuntu system do exist).  Me I'd go for a safe shutdown (*I use SysRq commands to shutdown if I need to in a hurry myself*)

Comment: Your screen *picture* shows what to me looks like 20.04 (not 22.04) but that's only the GRUB dialog (https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) that appears differently on boxes depending on machine *firmware*.. you can adjust that *delay* time down to 0 that on most hardware means it won't show (*but I'd not personally recommend that, as makes fixing problems harder; a shorter interval being my preference but not 0*) which is easy, but that doesn't match what you are describing in my view... and doesn't relate to *forced* or *brutal* shutdowns

Comment: Whilst the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/A/tips_and_tricks.html?highlight=grub) does reference getting grub to appear (*when interval is 0 or very low*), in my experience on faster hardware you can press the key too early or late & thus it doesn't achieve the end goal... Swap is optional (which will impact disk writes, but won't in my opinion touch brutal/forced shutdowns ... I'd always use command (SysRq `REISUO` for example) to force a safe shutdown! as its faster than hitting & holding power button anyway.

Comment: @guiverc I assure you that I'm using Lubuntu 22.04; the response of command `uname -a` is `Linux <hostname> 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: @guiverc No keyboard is connected to my system.

Comment: Sorry, my mention of 20.04 was just what it looked like to me & not meant as an accusation (*or need for response*)... I recall the discussion of *yellow* highlighted text & that decision, but not when it occurred, but a quick scan shows it appears to be *groovy* or 20.10 (ie. after 20.04's release) with the decision likely made mid-2020 thus maybe why I thought of 2020-April release..